# App preview in Tizen tv and emulator don't appear

Tags: react-native, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio, renative

App preview in Tizen tv and emulator don't appear
Hi I am developing an app for tizen tv, with react-native and renative. It already has the configuration to show a preview of the app when it is selected in the application bar of the home. But in emulator it behaves erratically, and most of the time it is not shown, in physical tv it is not shown at all.
I follow this instructions:

https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/guides/smart-hub-preview/implementing-personal-preview.html

Answer (score 0):

The demo project that Samsung shared on their Github can run very well.

Please refer it

https://github.com/SamsungDForum/SampleWebApps-PublicPreview